# The Question Grim Reaper

Tags: discussion

[Robert made a good point in the "future of money se" meta discussion](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362/future-of-money-se-what-should-be-the-next-logical-step/364#364). It's time to purge incomprehensible, inane or otherwise low quality posts.

I haven't participated in an SE meta much, so I'm not sure of the etiquette. So here's my candidate for elimination:

- https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10018/is-it-possible-that-i-can-raise-funds-for-stock-market-from-hedge-fund-firm-manag (Completely content free)
  -

Comment: can you provide a link to the discussion?

Comment: @JeffAtwood Voilà.

Comment: Looks like an excellent example of a question that isn't contributing anything positive to the site. Good work! Feel free to update this post with more examples as you come across them, or stop into [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22/show-me-the-money) and discuss edge-cases with your peers...

Comment: Is http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/when-to-change-dollar-to-euro another example of an elimination candidate, or is it best left here as an example of a bad question?

Comment: Now that we have acted on the question and deleted it, can we close this Meta question? else it will keep coming up as Open :)

Comment: I'd like to close this question  http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/531/do-you-have-a-good-story-about-instant-gratification as off topic.

Answer (score 2):

REAP THIS: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/531/do-you-have-a-good-story-about-instant-gratification

Being bored and wanting someone to tell you a story is understandable, but... That's why  Audible.com exists.