# What's up with "Trivial answer converted to comment"?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

So I went to the [grim reaper questions](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/the-question-grim-reaper) and I was going to answer with a question that I thought should be "reaped".  It was auto-magically converted to a comment.

How do I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I avoid this behavior?

Um... Don't write trivial answers? The logic behind this is pretty lenient; you have to be writing *next to nothing* for it to suck the answer into comment-land.

In this particular case, a short blurb about *why* you think the question should be closed would suffice. [In fact, I probably went overboard here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/the-question-grim-reaper/373#373) - a simple statement of, "Per the faq, questions not intended to solve real problems" should be enough.